# How to embed frameworks in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sdk, frameworks

I have a list of frameworks inside a folder, and I want to embed these in my x-code project and use it. I have tried adding the framework in the project and also link binaries with framework, so far nothing is working. I am not sure how to do this.